# multi-helper table for many-many-many-... relationship in flask-sqlalchemy

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

Many questions were about many to many problem which could be solved with a helper table. But how about many-many-many... If there existed a more elegant way to handle this problem.

I tried to put an issue on https://github.com/pallets/flask-sqlalchemy/issues/710. But this guy reject to answer the question, or I think it's a feature instead of question.But anyway, he closed my issue.

Here is the minimal sample code, which I would like to handle the relationship among A,B,C in this way.

```
Helper_table = db.Table('Helper_table',
                     db.Column('id_a', db.Integer,
                               db.ForeignKey('a.id')),
                     db.Column('id_b', db.Integer,
                               db.ForeignKey('b.id')),
                     db.Column('id_c', db.Integer,
                               db.ForeignKey('c.id'))
                )
```

Here the models for A,B,C.

```
class A(db.Model):  # A ORM
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(64), index=True, unique=True)

    bs = db.relationship(
        'B', secondary=Helper_table, lazy='dynamic')
    cs = db.relationship(
        'C', secondary=Helper_table, lazy='dynamic')

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<A {}>'.format(self.username)

class B(db.Model):  # B ORM
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(64), index=True, unique=True)


    as = db.relationship(
        'A', secondary=Helper_table, lazy='dynamic')
    cs = db.relationship(
        'C', secondary=Helper_table, lazy='dynamic')

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<B {}>'.format(self.username)

class C(db.Model):  # C ORM
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<C {}>'.format(self.id)
```

Here is the Test code for them.

```
def test():
    s1 = A(username="a1_"+str(uuid.uuid4()))
    s2 = A(username="a2_"+str(uuid.uuid4()))
    t1 = B(username="b1_"+str(uuid.uuid4()))
    t2 = B(username="b2_"+str(uuid.uuid4()))

    c1 = C()
    c2 = C()
    c3 = C()
    c4 = C()



    t1.as.append(s1)
    t1.cs.append(c1)


    t1.as.append(s2)
    t1.cs.append(c2)

    t2.as.append(s1)
    t2.cs.append(c3)

    t2.as.append(s2)
    t2.cs.append(c4)

    db.session.add(t1)
    db.session.add(t2)
    db.session.commit()
```

At the first time the idea came into my mind. I thought maybe the code above could solve the problem. Unfortunately, after run these code, I found it didn't work as I wished.

Here is the helper table shows in the database. Not as I expected.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/A9i2F.png

Maybe my idea was totally wrong. I should use the old-school method to solve the problem.

Comment: This is better done using raw sql than this sql alchemy. Just that you will be mindful to escape data where appropriate to ensure that sql injection attack is not possible

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to three-way many-to-many relationship in flask-sqlalchemy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23035662/how-to-three-way-many-to-many-relationship-in-flask-sqlalchemy)

Comment: No, it's no the same, what I ask actually is a design problem. It should be a feature. But the maintaner don't want to answer. Indeed, there should be an elegant code to solve the problem using sql-alchemy way. Just similar to solve the two many-many issues.